# Draggable function does not work as expected

Tags: angularjs, jsplumb, gantt-chart

I am trying to integrate jsPlump to Angular-Gantt as a plugin to implement task-dependency. I have added endpoints to tasks and connections beetween endpoints. Now I want to move these endpoints and connections with tasks.

At the beginning, I could not move them at all. When I move tasks, endpoints and connections stayed where they first appear.

Now, I try to use jsPlump.dragable function to do this process but it does not work as expected. Endpoints dispalys near of eachother and not on tasks. When I move tasks, they move but not with tasks. Also, when I release the mouse button, tasks keep moving with mouse move.

What can I do to solve this problem? The solution is dragable function or is there another option to do that?

**EDIT**

The code is a little large to share and has many dependencies to other libraries. Simply what I do is;

```
var taskElement = $($element).closest('.gantt-task');//TaskElement is the DOM element of Angular Gantt's task.
var left = instance.addEndpoint(taskElement, aq.jsPlumb.endpoint, {anchor: 'Left', uuid: task.id + 'Left'});
var right = instance.addEndpoint(taskElement, aq.jsPlumb.endpoint, {anchor: 'Right', uuid: task.id + 'Right'});

instance.draggable(taskElement);
```

Comment: Please provide code and/or a demo ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) reproducing your problem.

Comment: I have added some code.